# Create mask layer from paletted raster

Tags: qgis, raster, split-by-attribute

I have QGIS 2.18.
I have the ground truth of land type for France. That is a paletted raster (i think.. i'm new and maybe it is not the correct word)

I loaded a style.qml file for this raster and I get this:

```
0 : no data
1 : urban
2: Roads
...
21 : water
```

(all these values have an associate color on the raster visualisation ofc)

Based on that, can I split my raster into 21 different rasters, each one representing a single mask?

(And then merge them into one TIFF file and use it as the ground truth for a deep segmentation algorithm)

EDIT: 
I found a basic solution: I save my ground truth raster and I exclude all the values excepted the value I care about (e.g 17: trees). So I have to do it manually for my 21 classes.

Comment: QGIS has `split vector layer`, but I don't know of any equivalent tool for rasters. You could `polygonize` the raster, run `split vector layer` on the polygonized layer, then `clip raster by mask layer`. It doesn't seem much easier than exporting 21 different classes manually, though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by splitting up the raster, then merging it back together? Wouldn't that just give you the same thing you started with?

Comment: I want to have a tensor shape for my neural network like this : (Width, Height, nb_of_classes) with 0 or 1 for each elements.